# DateTime2(7) gives 0 padded value

Tags: sql-server

I want to save date in `datetime2(7)` format in my application's database.
I tried this:

```
@CreatedDate DateTime2(7)= getutcdate();
```

Then i found the value was this:

> 2016-08-02 15:02:14.687**0000**

I want 2016-08-02 15:02:14.**6871345** format.

What should i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`GETUTCDATE()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178635.aspx) returns a `DATETIME` value so will never have that sort of resolution.

Instead try [`SYSUTCDATETIME()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630387.aspx) as this does return a `DATETIME2` with a precision of 7 digits.

For example:

```
SELECT GETUTCDATE() AS UtcDate,
       SYSUTCDATETIME() AS SysUtcDate
```

Will give something like this:

```
╔═════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════════╗
║ UtcDate                 ║ SysUtcDate                  ║
╠═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════╣
║ 2016-08-02 09:49:54.347 ║ 2016-08-02 09:49:54.3486893 ║
╚═════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════════╚
```